# Error when creating a table with max length column in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, maxlength

I am creating a table in MS SQL and I want my column "name" to have the max length.

```
CREATE TABLE "example" (

"name"         character varying (MAX)       NULL, 
.....
```

but I receive an error as follows:

> Table has no text/image columns, Received an invalid column length from.

Do you have any idea what is wrong. Sorry I just started using MS SQL.

Comment: character varying is not MSSQL data type name.

Comment: You should start with the *docs*, especially if you just started. There's no `character` or `varying`. Check the [CREATE TABLE examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) in the docs

Comment: character varying(max) wont work, try either      varchar(max) or      char varying(max)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's not entirely true.
Microsoft has introduced ISO compatibility synonyms to SQL server which, in turn, point to the SQL server data types:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-synonyms-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If I use character varying(8000) I have no issue.. But varchar(max) or char varying(max) or character varying(max) do not work.

Comment: @zero they work. After Gospodin Tanev's comment I tried that statement and it works. Post something that can actually reproduce the error. Post the *actual error in full* too. I suspect it was thrown by some other script or code

Comment: @GospodinTanev That's new to me. And I have to say "eww". Why would you make a datatype name with a space in it

Comment: @GospodinTanev "ISO Compatibility" doesn't mean much. The SQL standard has multiple compatiblity levels and **no** database product goes beyond the basics. Part of the reason is that the standard is a compromise made by committee. Early on IBM (the creator of SQL) argued that expressions should be `4<field` because it was easier for them to write the parser.

Comment: @GospodinTanev the fact that `ORDER BY` became legal outside cursors only in 2008 doesn't make developers call for ISO compatibility either. That's at least a 10 years delay. Temporal tables? 12 years of grumbling. The reason? The vendors blocked stuff that would cause them trouble.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is correct, however based on the question from @zero and your initial comment, they can use `char varying(max)` instead of varchar(max), I know, its not very practical in my opinion to declare datatype with long names and space, it's just possible as the engine simply translates the synonym and that's what I pointed out. Just as we use `float` and `real` - they can both be declared with `float(n)` for (n) = 1-7 becomes `real` and (n) = 8 - 15 stays `float`.

Comment: The Java support in SQL-1999, something that seemed so important back then? Who cares now? Object-relational features that would *really* make our lives easier? Complex types at least? We have to parse JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for varchar(max) and remove quotes

```
create table example ([name] varchar(max),[othercol] int)
```

Comment: NVARCHAR(MAX) is also a possible answer depending on the field requirements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll be darned!  You are correct.  I've never seen varying(max).   Personally I don't  quotes

Comment: Yeah, its hard to notice the existence of these synonyms until you get api calls with them :D after the statement is complete.
For example, you can create a table by specifying national character varying:

`CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, VarCharCol national character varying(10)) `
VarCharCol is assigned an nvarchar data type, and all following metadata functions will report the column as an nvarchar(10) column. The metadata functions will never report them as a national character varying(10) column.

Comment: @GospodinTanev Love this site!  I learn something new every day!